# VBA for Reading from the Registry

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, registry

Is there code that will allow me to read the version of office installed on a machine, and location of the dlls from ms access?

So I have recently been convinced that late binding is the way to go with the automation my app performs. However, automation is the MAIN function of this app and I need to spin off different routines from some of the version specific code (mainly for ppt presentations).

So I am not really trying to sovle my issue with reference checking & IsBroken methods anymore because that won't help. But I still would like to know what verison of office is installed, what version of each of the office apps are installed (Excel 11.0, Outlook 11.0, etc), and the file paths to the dlls.

So I am wondering if I can get this information by reading the registry?

Comment: "what verison of office is installed"  Why?  How do you intend to use that information?  Can any of your target machine have more than one version of Office installed?  If so, what information do you want?

Comment: "file paths to the dlls"  Which DLLs, and why?  When setting a VBA reference to "Microsoft PowerPoint 11.0 Object Library", the file location on my machine is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\MSPPT.OLB"  What are you after with DLL locations?

Comment: @Hans...actually Hans they can't have more than one version of office installed on these machines as a matter of policy (but that is not to say some out there might just do it anyway). So the Office* folder is stored in different places depending on site's config...some places is C:\Programs Files\...  others its C:\Office...some places use a totally different drive all together. Basically, I am going to start using the late binding, but it seems that folks pitch that method to say, well if the automation doesn't work, atleast the rest of the app will. So I need a way to check which library...

Comment: (cont.)..is being used. So that I can adjust the routines called, per what version it is...perhaps the example below will solve this for me! thanks!

Comment: Hey, Justin.  Show us how you need to adjust your code in response to different Office application versions.  I've never had to do anything like that.

Comment: so there is not version specific syntax between say, ppt 2003-2010? I thought that I had read that within the explanation. I built all this stuff in Office 2007, but if the same code will work 2003 & 2010, then that is wonderful. I though that wasn't the case because I was getting a compile error on an oShape.TextFrame.TextRange = "*", but I noticed I forgot to change the declaration to an Object. But this is working great! Thanks for all the answers/advice. I can tell the late binding takes longer to generate, but that is much better than an error with no ppt!!! :)

Comment: I haven't programmed PowerPoint and don't know about version specific syntax differences.  I hoped you showing an example of code you need to adapt might allow us to help you better.  Here is a quote from Microsoft: *In general, when you are working with multiple versions of Office, the best practice is to test the database on the oldest version of Office and the oldest version of Microsoft Windows that you plan to support. Make sure all of the references are fixed. When the database is opened by using a newer version of Office or Windows, the references still work.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your late binding surely all you need is the version agnostic `*.Application` progid?

```
Dim oApp As Object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Debug.Print "ver " & oApp.Version, "build " & oApp.Build
oApp.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

**SysCmd** method can be used to determine system information about Microsoft Access

**`SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessVer)`** - will return access version 
**`SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir)`** - will return file path to dlls